# Why is the volume of a parallelepiped given three vectors zero?

Tags: vectors, volume, cross-product

I'm trying to find the volume of a parallelepiped given three vectors:

- $A=(-2,3,1)$
- $B=(1,1,2)$
- $C=(1,2,3)$

So,

\begin{align*}
V &= \| C \cdot (A \times B)\| \\
 &= \| (1,2,3) \cdot \big((-2,3,1)\times (1,2,3)\big)\| \\
&= \| (1,2,3) \cdot (5,5,-5)\| \\
&= 0 \\
\end{align*}

Why is $0$? I checked the cross and dot products on Symbolab and they're fine. But I don't know what I'm missing. Any help?

Comment: The vectors are not linearly independent.

Comment: The three vectors lie in a plane. That makes the parallelepiped very flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a surprise since $A+7B-5C=0$ which means $A$,$B$ and $C$ are in the same plane.